# Create command in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I created entity User with fields: name, password, email. Do I really need to create a `service` that extracts only the records of my email?(`$this->getContainer()->get('myservice)`)
Please, help me to solve this problem.

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em
           ->createQuery('SELECT u.email FROM ModelBundle:User u')
        ->getResult();
        $this->getContainer()
        output->writeln($query);
    }
```

If i start my command, i have error

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException] Attempted to call method "getDoctrine" on class "Elastica\CoreBundle\Comman d\EmailCommand".`

Comment: You should inject the service container in your command, and then get doctrine from this container

Comment: @Med Could you write the answer below? I note your answer to this question right. Maybe someone needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **$this->getDoctrine()** you should use **$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')**

As $this->getDoctrine() short-cut is available only in controllers